# C# Server using TcpListener connects the first Client, but second Client timeouts and fails to connect, why?

Tags: c#, server, tcplistener

I tried switching code to following async calls for Server.
I still am getting same issue.  First client connects and interacts fine.
The Second client get stuck with SocketException 10060 (Timeout)

Despite switching over to Async calls, second client is still timing out
Any hints or suggestions are welcomed.
Server code

```
Console.WriteLine("Initialized Server Data");
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Server......");
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
            tcpListener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine($"Server Started on Port: {Port}.");

            tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ConnectionCallback, null);
```

ConnectionCallback

```
TcpClient _client = tcpListener.EndAcceptTcpClient(_result);

            //add client to server list
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= MaxPlayers; i++)
            {
                if (Clients[i].tcp.socket == null)
                {
                    //found empty client slot on server add client
                    Clients[i].Connect(_client, this);

                    i = MaxPlayers * 2;
                }
            }
            if (i < MaxPlayers + 2)
            {
                Program.WriteConsoleLine($"{_client.Client.RemoteEndPoint} failed to connect: Server is full.", ConsoleColor.Red, ConsoleColor.Black);
            }
            tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ConnectionCallback, null);
```

Clients[i].Connect(...)

```
public void Connect(TcpClient _socket, Server _actveServer)
            {
                ActiveServer = _actveServer;

                socket = _socket;
                socket.ReceiveBufferSize = dataBufferSize;
                socket.SendBufferSize = dataBufferSize;

                netStream = socket.GetStream();
                ReceivedData = new Packet();
                receiveBuffer = new byte[dataBufferSize];

                Program.WriteConsoleLine($"{_socket.Client.RemoteEndPoint} connect success!!", ConsoleColor.Cyan, ConsoleColor.Black);

                Program.WriteConsoleLine($"Sending IntialWelcome as a hello to {_socket.Client.RemoteEndPoint}", ConsoleColor.DarkCyan, ConsoleColor.Black);
                ActiveServer.Packer.Send_InitialWelcome(id);

                netStream.BeginRead(receiveBuffer, 0, dataBufferSize, ReceiveDataCallback, null);
            }
```

ReceiveDataCallback

```
private void ReceiveDataCallback(IAsyncResult _result)
            {
                try
                {
                    int _byteLen = netStream.EndRead(_result);
                    if (_byteLen <= 0)
                    {
                        ActiveServer.Clients[id].Disconnect();
                        return;
                    }

                    byte[] _data = new byte[_byteLen];
                    Array.Copy(receiveBuffer, _data, _byteLen);

                    ReceivedData.Reset(HandleData(_data));
                }
                catch (Exception _err)
                {
                    Program.WriteConsoleLine($"Error receiving TCP data: {_err}", ConsoleColor.Red, ConsoleColor.Black);
                    ActiveServer.Clients[id].Disconnect();
                }

                netStream.BeginRead(receiveBuffer, 0, dataBufferSize, ReceiveDataCallback, null);
            }
```

Send Packet function and callback

```
public void SendPacket(Packet _packet)
            {
                try
                {
                    if(socket != null)
                    {
                        netStream.BeginWrite(_packet.ToArray(), 0, _packet.Length(), EndPackagingData, netStream);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception err)
                {
                    Program.WriteConsoleLine($"Error sending data to Player {id}, via TCP: {err}", ConsoleColor.Red, ConsoleColor.Black);
                }
            }

            private void EndPackagingData(IAsyncResult _result)
            {
                netStream.EndWrite(_result);
            }
```

Comment: Catching an excepton without handling it is a bad practice.

Comment: Code never enters any of the catch statements.

Comment: I am new to try/catches, did some research and will implement todo code later.  I am still puzzled why only 1 client will connect.

Comment: What's the server state when the second client was connecting? You printed a lot messages, could you add them in your question?

Comment: None of the exception comments pop
I get the connect messages and username/password from first client and then server goes back into waiting loop printing message that it is waiting as it sleeps between checks of tcpListener.Pending()

Comment: I saw _Send xxxx:60123_, if 60123 is the port the server is listening, make sure you didn't send data to that port.

Comment: Does simply blocking on AcceptSocket work? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.acceptsocket?view=net-6.0

Comment: We have no idea what your code does after accepting the first connection, because that's as far as you've shown us. If, for instance, the code does something blocking then of course it cannot accept further connections. Prefer to use async mechanisms built into the language/framework over using explicit threads, and if you need help, show us a complete example without extraneous exception/logging code.

Comment: Updated to add the Client connect and communication thread
I use the tcpListener.Pending() within the sleep loop to check for pending clients so i do not get stuck at the blocking call tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient().
I use the Endpoint returned by tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient() to communicate with Client and pass data

Comment: I switch code(as you see above**Updated**) to use Async calls to try if that would solve issue.  Sadly i am experience the same issue.  Client 1 connects and can interact with server.  Client  2 times out at connection returning 10060

Comment: I had my friend run my server and i was able to connect both of my computers to it
He was also able to run 3 of my clients on his pc and connect. 

Code works great.  Seems i have a firewall/router issue
i am not able to multiclient connect from same pc as he can

Thank you for the suggestions and input!!
If you have any further please let me know thanks